# Algún comando para Python para enviar un correo cuando corra el programa ya sea 1 y 0 (por ejemplo un sensor de puerta)

Tags: python

Tengo uno pero ya no es compatible con mi python (uso 3.5) y no se como adaptarlo este es 2.x y no me soporta la libreria urlib2).

```
 import urllib2
import json
#Esta es la funcion que usara el script para enviar las notificaciones
def sendNotification(token, channel, message):
   data = {"body" : message,"message_type" : "text/plain"}
   req = urllib2.Request('http://api.pushetta.com/api/pushes/{0}/'.format(channel))
   req.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
   req.add_header('Authorization', 'Token {0}'.format(token))
   response = urllib2.urlopen(req, json.dumps(data))
#Enviamos la notificacion en formato '&amp;lt;strong&amp;gt;Apikey+Canal+Mensaje&amp;lt;/strong&amp;gt;'
sendNotification("APIKEY", "Aprenderpython", "Este es un mensaje enviado con Raspberry Pi!")
#Sacamos por pantalla de que ya se ha enviado el mensaje
print "Mensaje enviado, listo!"
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya que parece que estás usando la API de pushetta, lo más simple sería usar su propia librería Python: `pip install`[`pushetta`](https://pypi.org/project/pushetta/).

Ejemplo de su documentación:

```
from pushetta import Pushetta

API_KEY="00112233445566778899aabbccddeeff00112233"
p=Pushetta(API_KEY)
p.pushMessage("raspi", "Hello World")
```

Si quieres usar la API "a mano" puedes usar la biblioteca [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) que te simplifica enormemente el uso de HTTP y consumo de APIs REST.

Finalmente, si no quieres instalar ninguna librería extra, puedes "traducir" tu script python 2 a python 3 cambiando `urllib2` por `urllib.request` como se muestra por ejemplo [aqui](/https://stackoverflow.com/a/14510349/126482)